# Updating elements in angular 2 with ngFor loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to learn how a few things work in the new Angular. I have previously only used AngularJS, so I am trying to reach myself the new TypeScript version. If I have a template that loops through my data object, how can I set up a model so that when something is tapped (or clicked) that it will only reflect the updates on that element in the template.

What I am trying to achieve is that if the reportImage is clicked, only the element with whatever p.id is passed will have the information updated.

This was my current attempt at trying this all out and I don't believe that I am using the ngModel correctly.

Template:

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let p of posts" [(ngModel)]="post[p.id]">
<img [src]="p.img" (tap)="reportImage($event, p.id)">
<button>
  <i [name]="icon.name" class="fa {{ icon.class }}"></i>
</button>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
 public tap: number = 0;

 buttonClass(id: number) {

    if(this.post[id].icon.name === 'heart-o') {
      this.post[id].icon.class = 'heart';
    }
    else {
      this.post[id].icon.name = 'heart-o';
      this.post[id].icon.class = 'heart-o';
    }
  }

  reportImage(times, id: number) {
    this.tap++;
    if(this.tap % 2 === 0) {
      this.buttonClass(id);
    }
  }
```

Any additional direction or tutorials to learn from would be great.

Comment: ngModel in Angular is similar to ng-model in angularjs: it's used for bidirectional binding between a form element (input, select, textarea) and a model. Using it on a div doesn't make sense, just like ng-model on a div didn't make sense in angularjs. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but ngModel has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @JBNizet - Thanks for the info. I apologize for the crude example of what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to create a way that when a user clicks `reportImage` it will just update the `icon.class` for that element and not everything in the `posts` object. So, I was trying to pass the `posts.id` to the `reportImage` function so that it would just update that particular element.

Comment: @zeropsi `ngFor` is used only for list the array (object array, number, etc.) You use ngFor in the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of posts">
<img [src]="p.img" (click)="reportImage($event, p)">
<button>
  <i [name]="p.icon.name" class="fa {{ p.icon.class }}"></i>
</button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
reportImage(times, currentOne) {
    this.tap++;
    if(this.tap % 2 === 0) {
      this.buttonClass(currentOne);
    }
  }

buttonClass(currentOne) {

    if(currentOne.icon.name === 'heart-o') {
      currentOne.icon.class = 'heart';
    }
    else {
      currentOne.icon.name = 'heart-o';
      currentOne.icon.class = 'heart-o';
    }
  }
```

*There are plenty of mistake in your code.
1. `Icon` - referring to what ?. Is it a global variable
2. `(tap)` - Is it your custom event, If not use `click` instead of `tap`

Answer (score 0):

What I understood in your question is that, when you click on image you want to change the data in that particular object that the image belongs to you. Just go through this code that I've written in stackblitz which is very similar to yours.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qfv7v